# Last Character Of A Variable Name

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to find last character of a variable. My code is:

```
trace(this[String.fromCharCode(num) + i]);
```

I also need second character by backwards. Sorry for my English.

Edit:
I think I couldn't explain it exactly. I have some variables. One of them is: this["h5"]
I want it to return 5.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
function lastNameChar(target:DisplayObject):String
{
    return target.name.substr(target.name.length - 1, 1);
}

trace(lastNameChar(this["h5"])); // 5
```

Comment: What exactly do the variables `h5` etc refer to? Objects on the stage?

Comment: it's this["h5"] = new Object(); this["h5"].piece = null; this["h5"].x = 347; this["h5"].y = 147;

Comment: @nikel You realize the correct syntax for defining a variable is `var h5:Object = new Object()` right? I was under the impression that you were using this syntax to reference objects on the stage.

Comment: @nikel To be honest, I can't think of a reason that you'd need the variable names. Maybe what you're actually after is an object, array or dictionary that maps values to keys, so that you can get the value of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make use of a string's `length` and get characters of it using [charAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#charAt%28%29).

So, if you had the following:

```
var myString : String = "abcdefg";
```

You could do this to get the last character:

```
myString.charAt(myString.length - 1); // (since the first character is at index 0
```

and to get the next to last character:

```
myString.charAt(myString.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLastCharInString($s:String):String
{
return $s.substr($s.length-1,$s.length);
}

    function getSecondLastCharInString($s:String):String
{
return $s.substr($s.length-2,$s.length);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 319 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type String.